# How we can refresh page until certain text is appeared on UI using karate framework?

Tags: user-interface, karate

Scenario is as below:

1. Upload file in s3 bucket.
2. Open the application
3. Refresh page till the data from uploaded file is appeared on UI

I have tried refresh(), waitUntilText, waitUntil till text is appeared. However, its not working. The text is appeared after some time (which is not consistent to provide delay) and need to refresh the page to have check is the data is updated on UI under certain web element.

Comment: please read this section of the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#retry - other than that I really have no suggestions

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas retry() is working for me along with count and interval parameter.